# Cloud Run Jobs - resources distribution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

How are the memory and the CPU distributed among the tasks in the cloud run job.
For example, what if I have 32 GB and 8 cores and asked for 8 parallel tasks, how much memory and cpu I should expect from for each task?

Thanks

Comment: This question doesnt make much sense, cloud run runs your container, if the container has access to 32GB of mem and 8 vCPU cores, it's up to you how you use those in your own container, not cloud run.

Comment: Very easy: 1 Task = 1 instance. Nothing is shared.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, what is instance in this context? I allocated 8 cores to the job and 5 parallel tasks,  so it it creates 5 "instances" of the same job so each will get 8 cores?

Comment: Yes. 1 instances is 1 container running on a "VM". So 8 CPU per instance with 5 task, you will pay for 40 CPUs

Comment: You can find details here, in the top of the page: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs

`Each task runs one container instance` Call the container instance as you wish: VM, pod (like Kubernetes),... It's the design of Cloud Run. It scales horizontally by adding instances. And you pay only when your code is running. I mean, if 4 tasks take 1 hour and the 5th take 1 minutes, you will pay 4 instances for 1m (CPU + Memory) and 1 instance for 1m

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere. In you example I do believe that you meant
(you will pay 4 instances for 1H (CPU + Memory) and 1 instance for 1m)

Comment: `In your example I do believe that you meant (you will pay 4 instances for 1H (CPU + Memory) and 1 instance for 1m)` Yes I guess.

Comment: Thanks guillaume blaquiere for your inputs on this.I missed them in my answer. @LeonBam I have updated my answer with some inputs along with the above comments for better community visibility. Can you have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

> How are the memory and the CPU distributed among the tasks in the cloud run job?

It depends on the Task configuration as cloud run manages the cpu allocation internally according to task configuration options.Such as [task-timeout](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/task-timeout),[parallelism](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/parallelism) and other options in [create-jobs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs).

> For example, what if I have 32 GB and 8 cores and asked for 8 parallel tasks, how much memory and cpu I should expect from each task?

As @guillaume blaquiere mentioned above

> `1 Task = 1 instance. Nothing is shared`.Which means Each task runs one container instance. Same has been documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/create-jobs#:%7E:text=Each%20task%20runs%20one%20container%20instance). As you have allocated 8 cores to the job and 5 parallel tasks,Cloud run creates 1 instance for each task. 1 instance means 1 container running on a "VM". So 8 CPU per instance with 5 tasks, you will pay for 40 CPUs.
>
> As each task runs one container instance. Call the container instance as you wish: VM, pod (like Kubernetes),... It's the design of Cloud Run. It scales horizontally by adding instances. And you pay only when your code is running. I mean, if 4 tasks take 1 hour and the 5th takes 1 minute, you will pay 4 instances for 1m (CPU + Memory) and 1 instance for 1m.